# How to avoid an issue with getFormula/setFormula in French instead of English?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, localization, google-sheets-formula

In order to copy a sheet from a spreadsheet to another, I proceed to a copy. Therefore, even if that seems to work I noticed that sometimes, formulas are not copied properly.

So, I decided to copy formulas from the source Spreadsheet to the destination spreadsheet, and here is my issue.
Even if I admit formulas are copied, they are in English, but both my source and destination spreadsheets language settings are in French. So that, instead of RECHERCHEV in my formulas (this is an example), I get VLOOKUP. The same for SOMME/SUM, SIERREUR/IFERROR, etc.
So that, the formula is not understood on the spreadsheet in the end, and I get the value : #ERROR!

I don't know if this is a known issue, none of my research are satisfying for what I get. 
Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Here is what I tried to do to solve that :

1)I tried to change the spreasheet settings for using only english formulas, but I have an issue with "," and ";"...which logic does not appears to me : accept ",", but in the copied sheet does not accept ",".

2)I tried to replace in the formula some elements, for a translation :

```
 formulaToWrite.toString().replace(/([VLOOKUP])+/g, "RECHERCHEV");
formulaToWrite.toString().replace(/([SUM])+/g, "SOMME");
```

==> does not seem to work

```
formulaToWrite.toString().replace("VLOOKUP", "RECHERCHEV");
formulaToWrite.toString().replace("SUM", "SOMME");
```

==> does not seem to work

Here is the function I use to copy formulas from one sheet (from a spreadsheet) to another (from another spreadsheet) :

```
function copyFormulas(sourceSheet,destinationSheet){

  var rangeSource = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeSourceA1=rangeSource.getA1Notation();
  var rangeDestination=destinationSheet.getRange(rangeSourceA1);

  var formulasSource = rangeSource.getFormulas();
  Logger.log(formulasSource); 

  //loop for writing formulas
  for (var i in formulasSource) {
    for (var j in formulasSource[i]) {
      var formulaToWrite=formulasSource[i][j];

      if (formulaToWrite!=""){

        var r_celDestination=rangeDestination.getCell(parseInt(i)+1, parseInt(j)+1);
        r_celDestination.setFormula(formulaToWrite);

      }//if (formulaToWrite!=""){

    } //for (var j in formulasSource[i]) {    
  }//for (var i in formulasSource) {  

}//function copyFormulas(sourceSheet,destinationSheet){
```

And here is what I get with the Logger.log : (this is an extract from it : I squeezed some lines without any formula) :

```
[[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , =E5, , , , =E5, , , , =E5, , , , =E5, , , , =E5, , , ],  [, , , =SUM(E13/E32), =SUM(E7:F11), , , =SUM(I13/I32), =SUM(I7:J11), , , =SUM(M13/M32), =SUM(M7:N11), , , =SUM(Q13/Q32), =SUM(Q7:R11), , , =SUM(U13/U32), =SUM(U7:V12), , , =SUM(Y13/Y32), =SUM(Y7:Z12), , , ],  [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , =IF(ISBLANK(X3),"date prix revient vide",IFERROR(IF(X3>=importEmployesEtParamFichier!H15,importEmployesEtParamFichier!I15,importEmployesEtParamFichier!I14),"erreur")), =Y32*X40, , , ],
etc.
```

EDIT : 
After further investigations, I realized I forgot to assign the replacing result to the variable. Eventually, I used this function :

```
function translateFormula(formulaToWrite){

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("SUM")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("SUM", "SOMME")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("VLOOKUP")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("VLOOKUP", "RECHERCHEV")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("IFERROR")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("IFERROR", "SIERREUR")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("IF")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("IF", "SI")}//after IFERROR

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("FALSE")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("FALSE", "FAUX")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("TRUE")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("TRUE", "VRAI")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("MATCH")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("MATCH", "EQUIV")}

  while (formulaToWrite.indexOf("ISBLANK")!=-1){formulaToWrite=formulaToWrite.toString().replace("ISBLANK", "ESTVIDE")}

  return formulaToWrite;

}//function translateFormula(formulaToWrite){
```

And my main function became :

```
function copyFormulas(sourceSheet,destinationSheet){

  var rangeSource = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeSourceA1=rangeSource.getA1Notation();
  var rangeDestination=destinationSheet.getRange(rangeSourceA1);

  var formulasSource = rangeSource.getFormulas();
  Logger.log(formulasSource); 

  //loop in formulasSource
  for (var i in formulasSource) {
    for (var j in formulasSource[i]) {
      var formulaToWrite=formulasSource[i][j];

      if (formulaToWrite!=""){

        formulaToWrite=translateFormula(formulaToWrite);
        formulasSource[i][j]=formulaToWrite;

        var r_celDestination=rangeDestination.getCell(parseInt(i)+1, parseInt(j)+1);
        r_celDestination.setFormula(formulaToWrite);

      }//if (formulaToWrite!=""){

    } //for (var j in formulasSource[i]) {  

  }//for (var i in formulasSource) {  

}//function copyFormulas(sourceSheet,destinationSheet){
```

Now I have another issue : sheets says it doesn't recognize the pasted formula, but if I get into it, add a blanck in the end and validate, it accepts it without any other issue. Just entering and validating is not enough. I therefore have to find a way to go through it, but despite my efforts, it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please make Logger.log(formulasSource) to know what is the getFormulas() function returning? Also please share a copy of the spreadsheet (without any personal/private information) where you can replicate the problem.

Comment: I would like to share the spreadsheet, but it's on a company G-suite and there are some no-share rules that keeps me from sharing this :s However, I made a Logger.Log. I will add it to the post.

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: well I intended to change the formula like if I was translating by myself, but the result remains unchanged when I look at the result, as well when I look at the Logger. So I guess this is not the good way, or a formula cannot be used as a normal string, or...I made a mistake. Do you have any idea of what should work ?

Comment: Your target spreadsheet have an issue or a setting problem, because you should not even need to use translateFormula, it should be done automatically. Can you try with a copy of the target Spreadsheet?

Comment: I totally agree with you, I'm surprised of having to struggle with that. If you mean a copy of the one I'm working on, the sharing rule is still the same. Nonetheless, I managed differently : because one of the sheets is a template for the others with the same formulas (and identical for both source and destination spreadsheet), I used a getFormula/setFormula direclty from this one in the destination spreadsheet. And in this case, that works. But how ? Still a mystery for me.